# Symlink to node_modules using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, node-modules

I have some resources in node_modules folder. Since it's a private folder is there a way to access it by creating a Symlink using vanilla javascript or a framework? and how? for example this resource will never be found even thought the path is correct.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/emojionearea/dist/emojionearea.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/emojionearea/dist/emojionearea.min.js"></script>
```

web config file

```
 var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
 entry: './src/js/app.js',
  output: {
 filename: 'build.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  port: 4000,
  public: 'localhost:4000'
 },
 devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
 module: {
  rules: [
   {
    // set up standard-loader as a preloader
    enforce: 'pre',
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'standard-loader',
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    options: {
      // Emit errors instead of warnings (default = false)
      error: false,
      // enable snazzy output (default = true)
      snazzy: true
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
      'file-loader'
      ]
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Comment: this depends entirely on  your server setup.  Can you share that?

Comment: @Paul see the edited question

Comment: You have webpack, and you’re packing it-you don’t access modules directly like that. Check out a modern web dev tutorial.